# Does pyreverse work when some of the modules are provided in Cyton format ?(*.so files)

Tags: python, uml, pyreverse

I am tryint to learn a module that I would like to have the UML diagrams for it
Some of the classes are in binary format (.so)

Will pyreverse work in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried and it does not work
It stops when it runs into the so files....